# Resolve option on error not showing up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using `Visual Studio Professional 2013` and I can't see resolve option after right clicking on error. Where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of "Resolve error" being an option in Visual Studio.  In most cases, I don't think Visual Studio would be able to resolve an error on its own.

Another feature that that might help though is the "Show Error Help".  It doesn't appear by right clicking on the code causing the error in the code editor, but it appears if you right click on the error message in the Error List window below the code editor

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This option won't suggesting you what namespace should be added like resolve does.